# Animation with CSS selector not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

My HTML:

```
<div id="composite-field">
        <input type='email' name='email' class='input animate' value='' placeholder='E-mail'>
        <input type='submit' id='submit' class='submit animate' value='>'>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.animate { -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }    

html body div.body-container form div#composite-field {
            position: relative; float: left;
            width: 80%; height: 100px; margin: 0 10%; padding: 0;
        }

        html body div.body-container form div#composite-field input[type=email] {
            float: left;
            width: 90%; height: 100px; margin: 0; padding: 0 6% 0 4%;

            border: 0; outline: none;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
            background-color: #eab94e; color: rgba(26, 60, 88, 0.9);

            z-index: 10;
        }

        html body div.body-container form div#composite-field input[type=submit] {
            position: absolute; float: none; clear: both; top: 0; right: 5%;
            min-width: 80px; width: auto; height: 100px; margin: 0; padding: 0;

            border: 0; border-radius: 0; outline: none; -webkit-appearance: none;
            background-color: #2e4856; color: #eab94e;
            z-index: 11;
        }

        html body div.body-container form div#composite-field input[type=email],
        html body div.body-container form div#composite-field input[type=submit] { font-family: "Fjalla One", sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 40px; letter-spacing: normal; }

        html body div.body-container form div#composite-field input[type=email]:focus { 
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 60, 88, 0.9);
        }

        html body div.body-container form div#composite-field input[type=submit]:hover { opacity: 0.5; }
```

Now problem is here, the width of 20% doesn't get animated. It worked before. And I can't seem to figure out why it's not now...

```
html body div.body-container form div#composite-field input[type=email]:focus ~ input[type=submit] { width: 20%; }
```

Do I have an error with my css somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the initial width defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your submit button had a width of "auto", that was transitioning to 80% (the width was only set with min-width). If you set a width on it, the transition will work. Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/znm63rky/15/

```
html body div.body-container form div#composite-field input[type=submit] {
    width: 80px;
}
```